# Dagger 2.10 - ContributesAndroidInjector annotation

Tags: android, dagger-2

I've just implemented `dagger.android` as per [documentation](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html). First incorrect thing written there is existence of `HasActivityInjector` that was easily replaced with `HasDispatchingActivityInjector`.

Another thing mentioned there is usage of `@ContributesAndroidInjector` annotation that should simplify source creation a bit... But I cannot find such annotation neither via Android studio autocomplete nor in their [JavaDoc](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/) and [link](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/android/ContributesAndroidInjector.html) in the documentation redirects me to 404 site. How can i use the annotation? Or can I?

**Edit**: I'm using

```
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
```

where `daggerVersion = '2.10'`

Comment: HasActivityInjector and ContributesAndroidInjector are brand new, and may not be in Maven yet. Can you tell us exactly which version of dagger.android you're using?

Comment: I've edited my question - I'm using `2.10` version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@ContributesAndroidInjector is in [HEAD](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/ContributesAndroidInjector.java), added [ten days ago](https://github.com/google/dagger/commit/954ba085bed6cd21d630dad1f72212628815513d). It is not yet in a numbered release in Maven, but I'd imagine it will be shortly. Until then, you can download or clone the repository [directly from Github](https://github.com/google/dagger) (click the green button).

Edit: `@ContributesAndroidInjector` was released in Maven under version 2.11-rc1. Also `HasDispatchingActivityInjector` interface is now called `HasActivityInjector` as per documentation

Comment: Thanks, I should have checked the repository before asking.